# HttpSelfHostServer optimization

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, webserver

I hope you can provide some help or info with HttpSelfHostServer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver(v=vs.118).aspx

we have implemented above server in service app, used custom DelegatingHandler which we added to HttpSelfHostConfiguration MessageHandlers and override base SendAsync function where the message is processed

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

now everything works fine, fast but at some point after 20h there is a glitch on server where it stops processing message for 40s and after that it processes all the message + one that were queued from that point. after that it starts to work normal.it was like the queue on HttpSelfHostServer was full, can't find a way to trace this.

clients which are querying the service is java http ajax post to the service every 100ms, requesting some status, json data.

if there some limits in above web server which can be changed, like Max Concurrent Sessions, Max Concurrent Calls, and Max Concurrent Instances... or did someone had same or similar issue

note:OS is Server 2012 r2, tried to change the host servers but same problem

Comment: Are the messages discarded or is there just a pause? Could this be GC related?

Comment: Use Windows performance monitor to watch the thread pool usage and see if the slowness is caused by thread creation. Without collecting further info on the slowness itself like that, this question cannot be answered at all.

Comment: spender:messages are not discarded, they are just paused, not sure for the GC, thanks for reply

Comment: Lex:thanks for the info, i have put the performance counters on the process for Lock and Thread Performance Counters (.NET CLR Locks AndThreads) hope i will have more info